# What is a good free (or cheap) solution for remote backups on Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, ftp, network-attached-storage, remote

I have been pulling my hair out trying to implement a remote backup solution for my Windows server on very limited resources.  My off-site storage is a NAS drive that only has FTP capabilities, not SFTP or SSH, so I also require something that will encrypt the files as it transfers them over the Internet.  There is not much of a budget for software, and most of the standard server backup solutions run in the hundreds of dollars.  So far all of the cheap solutions that I have tested are unreliable or just don't work at all.  So far, the closest I have gotten has been Ace Backup 3, but I have been unsuccessful in getting it to backup all of my files properly.  Can anyone recommend a solution that would:

1. Perform nightly incremental backups
   to FTP
2. Compress and encrypt files for
   transfer
3. Send e-mail notifications
4. Be reliable and provide a method for
   verifying the backups
5. Cost under $100

This is driving me nuts, and I would love to have it off of my plate!  Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I don't understand why something as important as backups doesn't get a budget. I assume your company has paid thousands for the server, thousands for the OS and software that goes on the server, why not budget hundreds for a decent backup solution?

Comment: It's not because the company doesn't value backups, it's just that the cash flow is a bit tight and we need a budget solution until revenue is increased and a more suitable solution can be implemented.

Comment: I would have suggested backuppc but it doesn't do FTP, only rsync over SSH

Comment: Cost under $100 in what currency and over what time period (hour/day/week/month/year/forever)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any backup solution that will do what you are asking.  However, you could script a job that will do what you need...

You can use NTBackup to do the backup, have 7-Zip compress it, have Gnu Privacy Guard encrypt it, then use the built-in ftp client to transfer it.

No email notifications, but you can have all of this logged and it is free (except for your time).

Example script for NTBackup: http://tim.mackey.ie/ASampleNTbackupScriptWithTheCurrentDatetimeInTheFilenameAndBackupLabel.aspx
7-Zip command line info: http://dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples
GPG command line info: http://www.somacon.com/p107.php
Scripting FTP example: http://www.brettb.com/ScriptingWindowsFTP.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try SyncBackSE http://www.2brightsparks.com
I've used it for a number of years and it's been great.

does FTP backups
supports encryption & compression
sends email
logs jobs to HTML
Something like $30